# Choose a specific WiFi AP or Frequency

Tags: wifi, wpa-supplicant

My router (Google WiFi) have 2 access points with the same `ssid`: a 2.4GHz and a 5GHz. It seems that multicasting between these networks is unstable, so I want my raspberry (buster) to force a connection to the 2.4GHz network.

I've tried to add `bssid` and `bssid_blacklist` to the config, but it did not work. After a while, the connection changes to 5GHz

```
# /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
network={
        ssid="name"
        psk="*****"
        bssid=70:3A:CB:84:01:B4
        bssid_blacklist=70:3A:CB:84:01:B0
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

**Update:** None of the options seem to work. Here is a [discussion on the official forum](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=261222)

**Update 2:** `freq_list` seems to solve the problem, although many on the internet say it won't work. Here is my new config:

```
network={
        bssid=70:3A:CB:84:01:B4
        freq_list=2412 2417 2422 2427 2432 2437 2442 2447 2452 2457 2462
        ssid="..."
        psk="*****"
        bssid_blacklist=70:3A:CB:84:01:B0
}
```

My raspberry has been running on Buster Raspbian at 2.4GHz for a week now

Comment: https://w1.fi/cgit/hostap/plain/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf read up on `freq_list`

Answer (score 1):

Making that choice on the Raspberry Pi seems to be a problem. I would have thought that `bssid` or `bssid_blacklist` would have worked for you, at least. Being able to choose which access point to connect to based on BSSID is rather important...

I've tried to limit a Pi 3B+ to 2.4 GHz frequencies using the `freq_list` parameter in `wpa_supplicant.conf`, but with no success. [This seems to be a common problem](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=261222). Something seems to be broken in the Raspberry Pi's `wpa_supplicant`.

An ugly work-around would be to [choose a restrictive Wi-Fi country code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_WLAN_channels#5.0_GHz_(802.11j)_WLAN) that does not allow the 5 GHz frequency your router is using. Mainland China or Israel seem like good choices. By setting my Pi 3B+ to "Israel", which does not allow the 5 GHz frequency used by my router, it then connected using 2.4 GHz.

You *COULD* look at rebuilding the [Central Regulatory Domain Agent](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/developers/regulatory/crda#changing_regulatory_domains) (I think this is where the country Wi-Fi frequencies live, but I do not know for sure) to create your own custom "country" that only allows 2.4 GHz. Hopefully this work-around is good enough, though. :-)

**EDIT:** The link to the Raspberry Pi forum discussion of this problem was incorrect.

Comment: use freq_list outside network {}

Answer (score 0):

Change the APs SSID on the 2,4GHz and 5GHz so they do have separate names.

The other solution is to specify the parameter `freq_list` in the file `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`:

```
ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant

network={
    ssid="Your_AP"
    psk="Your_Passphrase"
    freq_list=2412 2437 2462
}
```

Ref.: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058622/how-to-force-to-linux-to-connect-only-5ghz-channel

Comment: Unfortunately, freq_list is currently broken in the Raspberry Pi OS.

Comment: Do you have a ref. to that?

Comment: This link is the discussion of the issue. I tested it myself and found the same issue. If I set the Wi-Fi county code to Israel, which is very restrictive for 5 GHz frequencies, my Pi would not connect to the router. (The router frequency was, obviously, one of those prohibited in Israel.) However, freq_list changes to wpa_supplicant.conf gave no results. raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=261222

Comment: Now Im curious, are you trying to use a channel that is prohibited by the country setting?

Comment: The opposite, actually: as a test, I tried to take advantage of a prohibited channel to force the Pi to use 2.4 GHz when the AP was using the same SSID for both 2.4 GHz and 5GHz. Limiting the frequencies the Pi would use through wpa_supplicant.conf was not working, and I was curious if the Pi would respect the CRDA regulatory list. It did.  It's an ugly work-around to the problem.

Comment: @Chris I need your advice, should I modify my answer and state something like "This should work, but as the state is today its broken" and could I include the Raspbian/Raspberry Pi OSversion you have tested ?!

Comment: in fact, it solved my problem, although many users on the internet say it won't work. i'm going to update my question

Comment: Perhaps you could up vote my answer, as it is in a -1 status now?

Comment: @MatsKarlsson Maybe remove the suggestion of making them different names ;)